# Javascript RegExp pattern match

Tags: javascript, regex

Please can anybody tell me how to match this below pattern:

```
var pattern = "^(?:http(s)?://)?(www\\.)?google\\..*/.*$";

var str = "https://www.google.co.in";
```

Comment: if str match in that pattern then return true otherwise false;

Comment: var pattern = "^(?:http(s)?://)?(www\\.)?google\\..*/.*$";

Comment: I am using this method str.match(new RegExp(pattern, 'mgi')); but it return false;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll find a nice example here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

BTW, your regexp seems to ask for a trailing slash.

Your sample here: http://regexr.com/3dmu3

Comment: Thanks @dfaure issue in last trailing slash.